# JavaScript ball in a canvas element does not follow cursor

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a simple program in JavaScript ES6 that makes a ball follow my cursor.  The ball moves, but it moves faster than my cursor.  Here is the code:

`index.html` is just a normal html document with a canvas element in it with an ID of "game_canvas"

`game.js`

```
// global vars
game_canvas = document.getElementById("game_canvas");

class Ball {
    constructor() {
        this.ctx = game_canvas.getContext("2d");
    }

    drawCircle(X, Y) {
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(X, Y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        this.ctx.fill();
    }
}

// MOUSE COORDS DETECTION
function getMousePos(event) {
    return {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY 
    };
}
// END COORDS DETECTION

let follower = new Ball(0, 0, game_canvas);

// START EVENT LOOP
game_canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    let mousePos = getMousePos(game_canvas, event);

    follower.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, game_canvas.width, game_canvas.height);
    follower.drawCircle(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);

}, false)
// END EVENT LOOP
```

**Update** I removed the canvas argument from the getMousePos() function.

Comment: Why is one of your arguments for the `getMousePos` function the canvas?  You're not using it there.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why, so an explanation would be appreciated, but inserting a viewport tag like this one:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

seems to have fixed the problem.